# How to avoid main libvlc error when using the python-vlc package?

Tags: python

Every time I use the module and call `vlc.MediaPlayer()`, I get a long list of error messages printed on the console. The top 20 rows are:

```
[000002635638b9b0] main libvlc error: stale plugins cache: modified C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\plugins\access\libaccess_concat_plugin.dll
[000002635638b9b0] main libvlc error: stale plugins cache: modified C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\plugins\access\libaccess_imem_plugin.dll
[000002635638b9b0] main libvlc error: stale plugins cache: modified C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\plugins\access\libaccess_mms_plugin.dll
[000002635638b9b0] main libvlc error: stale plugins cache: modified C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\plugins\access\libaccess_realrtsp_plugin.dll
[000002635638b9b0] main libvlc error: stale plugins cache: modified C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\plugins\access\libaccess_srt_plugin.dll
[000002635638b9b0] main libvlc error: stale plugins cache: modified C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\plugins\access\libaccess_wasapi_plugin.dll
[000002635638b9b0] main libvlc error: stale plugins cache: modified C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\plugins\access\libattachment_plugin.dll
[000002635638b9b0] main libvlc error: stale plugins cache: modified C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\plugins\access\libcdda_plugin.dll
[000002635638b9b0] main libvlc error: stale plugins cache: modified C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\plugins\access\libdcp_plugin.dll
[000002635638b9b0] main libvlc error: stale plugins cache: modified C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\plugins\access\libdshow_plugin.dll
```

The package version is: 3.0.12118.
I use it on a machine with Windows 10.

How can I get rid of this error? Or is there perhaps a better, more stable package to use for playing mp3 files?

Answer (score 5):

Took a lot of searching, but I found [this thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2388949) from 2018 that actually worked for me. There should be something called `vlc-cache-gen.exe` in your VLC folder. Run that in a command prompt, and pass in the plugins folder as an argument. Instantly fixed it for me:

`"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc-cache-gen.exe" "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\plugins"`